# Equivariant homomorphism in a non-abelian group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a  group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. A homomorphism $\phi$ from  $H$ to $G$ is said to be $G$-equivariant if $\phi (ghg^{-1})=g \phi (h)g^{-1}$, for all $g \in G$ and $h \in H$. I wants to compute all $G$-equivariant homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to a non-abelian group $G$ of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes with $p>q$.

I have tried this by property of homomorphisms, if we restrict ourself to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in the codomain then all homomorphisms are $G$-equivariant. But after that, I am not able to proceed. Please help me.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Every group of order $pq$, $p>q$ primes, has a unique Sylow $p$ so restricting to $p$-group in the codomain isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, clearly $G$ has a unique cyclic subgroup of order $p$. I want to classify all $G-equivarint$ maps from this cyclic subgroup to $G$.

Comment: I think all homomorphism from $Z_p$ to $G$ is equivariant. What's your attempt?

Comment: The image of any $p$-group is a $p$-group, so you have got all.

Comment: @HongyiHuang, how it can be possible that every map is equivariant since $Z_p$ is normal so $ghg^{-1}\in Z_p$ for all $g \in G$ and $h \in Z_p $. Now we have to check whenever $\phi(ghg^{-1})=g\phi(h)g^{-1}$. How can you say that all maps are $G- equivariant$, please notice that codomain is a non-abelian group of order pq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $G = \langle a\rangle:\langle b\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}_p:\mathbb{Z}_q$, a semidirect product, by $bab^{-1} = a^{m}$ for some $m$ such that $m^q\equiv 1\pmod p$. Let $\phi:\langle a\rangle\to G$ be a homomorphism, then $\phi(a) = a^n$ for some $n$, because $\phi(a)$ has order $1$ or $p$.

For any $g\in G$, $g = a^kb^l$ for some $k,l$. Then $gag^{-1} = a^kb^lab^{-l}a^{-k} = a^{m^l}$, and so $\phi(gag^{-1}) = a^{m^ln}$, while $g\phi(a)g^{-1} = a^kb^la^nb^{-l}a^{-k} = a^{m^ln}$. So they are equal.

Comment: Dear sir, your proof is looking good, but I am getting confused with this example. Kindly explain ,if we take $G=S_3={I,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)}$ and $H={I,(123),(132)}$ and consider the map $\phi$ from $H$ to $G$ by $(123) \longrightarrow (132)$ then  it can be seen that $\phi((12)(123)(12)^{-1})\neq (12)\phi((123))(12)^{-1}$. Clearly $\phi$ is not a $G-equivarint$ map.

Comment: $\phi((123)) = (132)$, and so $(12)\phi((123))(12)^{-1} = (12)(132)(12) = (123)$. And $(12)(123)(12)^{-1} = (132)$ so $\phi((12)(123)(12)^{-1}) = \phi((132)) = (123)$. They are equal.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused..thanks again.